# developing Blackberry apps

Tags: java, blackberry

I would like to create a new Blackberry app and i dont know where to start... I have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate installed and I was wondering if I could use it to develop BB native apps with it... or I should just go ahead and install Eclipse?? if so, I just went to [eclipse.org/downloads](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) and noticed they have MANY options... what do you guys reccomend?? 
thanks in advance
I've Windows 7 64 bit... should I get the 64bit version or 32??

It's also worth noting that I also have NEtbeans installed but just the php version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regards to BlackBerry development I think that you will be better off with Eclipse, reason being that there is a BlackBerry simulator plug-in, which I do not think is available for other platforms (there was/is something for Netbeans, however, I never managed to get it work). You might want to take a look [here](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/). You should find all you need.

Lastly, with regards to your operating system, one of the major differences between the versions (32 and 64bit) is the amount of RAM you can access, so if you have more than 3Gb of RAM, then, you should get the 64-bit version, if you have less, then the 32-bit version will be just fine.

Comment: According to http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/javaappdev/javaupdate.jsp I need 32 bit: "32-bit Windows® XP, Windows Vista™ or Windows 7 (Note: 64-bit versions require 32-bit Java and Eclipse)"

Comment: Also, which version of Eclipse?? there seem to be so many.. Eclipse Classic?

Comment: @NachoF Eclipse classic will do the job.

Comment: Im stuck again... now, when I try to install the Blackberry Java plugin it tells me I also need eclipse.org.ui but i cant figure out how to install that... please help

Comment: I do not use eclipse, what you might have to do is to download some extra plugins. On the other hand, Netbeans does have some mobile simulators, but they are pretty generic.

Answer (score 0):

In order to start developing for eclipse , first you should download eclipse ide(you can select 32 bit version for windows) from eclipse web site , then you have to install eclipse blackberry plugin from blackberry site (you need to signup in order to do this), then its done you can start developing blackberry project from eclipse menu.Here is a [blog post](http://burakdede.com/2010/06/15/using-eclipse-for-blackberry-development/) that i wrote.